# Pull several substrings from an input using specific characters to find them

Tags: python, string, character

I need to make a user created madlib where the user would input a madlib for someone else to use. The input would be something like this:

```
The (^noun^) and the (^adj^) (^noun^)
```

I need to pull anything between (^ and ^) so I can use the word to code so I get another input prompt to complete the madlib.

```
input('Enter "word in-between the characters":')
```

This is my code right now

```
madlib = input("Enter (^madlib^):")
a = "(^"
b = "^)"
start = madlib.find(a) + len(a)
end = madlib.find(b)
substring = madlib[start:end]
def mad():
   if "(^" in madlib:
      substring = madlib[start:end]
      m = input("Enter " + substring + ":")
      mad = madlib.replace(madlib[start:end],m)
   return mad
print(mad())
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.finditer()` to do this fairly cleanly by collecting the `.span()` of each match!

```py
import re

# collect starting madlib
madlib_base = input('Enter madlib base with (^...^) around words like (^adj^)): ')

# list to put the collected blocks of spans and user inputs into
replacements = []

# yield every block like (^something^) by matching each end and `not ^` inbetween
for match in re.finditer(r"\(\^([^\^]+)\^\)", madlib_base):
    replacements.append({
        "span": match.span(),  # position of the match in madlib_base
        "sub_str": input(f"enter a {match.group(1)}: "),  # replacement str
    })

# replacements mapping and madlib_base can be saved for later!

def iter_replace(base_str, replacements_mapping):
    # yield alternating blocks of text and replacement
    # skip the replacement span from the text when yielding
    base_index = 0  # index in base str to begin from
    for block in replacements_mapping:
        head, tail = block["span"]       # unpack span
        yield base_str[base_index:head]  # next value up to span
        yield block["sub_str"]           # string the user gave us
        base_index = tail                # start from the end of the span

# collect the iterable into a single result string
# this can be done at the same time as the earlier loop if the input is known
result = "".join(iter_replace(madlib_base, replacements))
```

Demonstration

```py
...
enter a noun: Madlibs
enter a adj: rapidly
enter a noun: house
...
>>> result
'The Madlibs and the rapidly house'
>>> replacements
[{'span': (4, 12), 'sub_str': 'Madlibs'}, {'span': (21, 28), 'sub_str': 'rapidly'}, {'span': (29, 37), 'sub_str': 'house'}]
>>> madlib_base
'The (^noun^) and the (^adj^) (^noun^)'
```

Comment: wow thank you this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your `mad()` function only does one substitution, and it's only called once.  For your sample input with three required substitutions, you'll only ever get the first `noun`.  In addition, `mad()` depends on values that are initialized outside the function, so calling it multiple times won't work (it'll keep trying to operate on the same `substring`, etc).

To fix it, you need to make it so that `mad()` does one substitution on whatever text you give it, regardless of any other state outside of the function; then you need to call it until it's substituted all the words.  You can make this easier by having `mad` return a flag indicating whether it found anything to substitute.

```
def mad(text):
    start = text.find("(^")
    end = text.find("^)")
    substring = text[start+2:end] if start > -1 and end > start else ""
    if substring:
        m = input(f"Enter {substring}: ")
        return text.replace(f"(^{substring}^)", m, 1), True
    return text, False


madlib, do_mad = input("Enter (^madlib^):"), True
while do_mad:
    madlib, do_mad = mad(madlib)

print(madlib)
```

```
Enter (^madlib^):The (^noun^) and the (^adj^) (^noun^)
Enter noun: cat
Enter adj: lazy
Enter noun: dog
The cat and the lazy dog
```